# How to warn (or error) when calling a function that is only implemented in base but not derived?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I'm really not sure how to title the question briefly.

Situation:

0. In C++20.
1. There is a `Base` as an interface, which specifies all the features (member functions) we have. There are also multiple derived classes that may implement a subset of features. Those functions are virtual functions.
2. There are also some functions that are identical across all derived classes.
3. There can be overloaded member functions.
4. We can statically check if a function is available in certain `Derived` by using SFINAE or concept.

Requirements:

6. When calling a non-implemented function by derived, there should be some compile warnings or errors.
7. As the number of features and derived can increase, I hope I don't need to change (or add) too much when such things happen.
8. The derived classes should also be able to convert to the base class.
9. Don't need to do too much for those "identical functions" mentioned in 2..

Maybe solutions (nonperfect):

10. Implements every feature in the `Base` and throws the error inside. Use `using` in `Derived` and put the function in the private field. Cons. If there's a new feature, we need to add it to every class. If we forget to do so, there's no warning.
11. Use pure virtual functions in `Base` and implement them in every `Derived` for every feature. Cons: A lot of implementations (and code) for those features that the `Derived` doesn't require, and the implementations are all the same - throw an error.

Update:

For the 11.: by "A lot of implementations", I made an example: https://godbolt.org/z/sW8eKjbhx.

Comment: Instead of describing potential code, please create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: "When calling a non-implemented function by derived"  This is a huge red flag to me, because then `Derived` cannot do everything a `Base` object can. Which you claim is the case by inheriting `Derived` from `Base`. Are you trying to create an `Object`? Push the methods to `Derived`, no need for base to know about them. And if there is a need, you have a design flaw.

Comment: Interesting, I just had a talk with someone about [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Your example seems to be a perfect fit to rethink your architecture towards such an approach, especially because it violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: Please explain 11 "Cons: A lot of implementations (and code) for those f" Its extremely difficult to help avoid writing code when you do not show the code. I do not see why thsi would result in "lot of implementations"

Comment: @Quimby I know this is not what an interface should be. In this case, I want to use the interface to list all the possibilities that all the derived classes can implement, and also allow them to be converted into the base class. Not sure if there's a better pattern to design this.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark this function as pure virtual. Then it has to be overriden in derived classes. Still it can have body.

```cpp
class Base {
public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

void Base::f() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The OP mentioned it in article 11 in the question together with the cons in their case.

Comment: @wohlstad but do you undersand the cons? What "A lot implementation" ? OPs premise is that the function has implementation in the base, so having an implementation in the base is no real con

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I admit I don't fully understand it. The question in general is not so clear. But it looks like the OP is aware of pure virtual methods, so I don't see the point in this answer.